# Dependecy Injection using Class into Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, class, dependency-injection

I'm using Express into a TypeScript project and I have the following situation

This is my route file

```
...
import findAllUsersFactory from "src/factory/FindAllUsers";

routes.get("/users", findAllUsersFactory().handle);
...
```

This is the factory where I do a sequence of injections

```
const findAllUsersFactory = () => {
  const findAllUserRepository = new PrismaUsersRepository();
  const findAllUsersBusiness = new FindAllUsersBusiness(findAllUserRepository);
  const findAllUsersController = new FindAllUsersController(findAllUsersBusiness);

  return findAllUsersController;
};
```

This is my Controller

```
class FindAllUsersController {
  constructor(private findUserBusiness: FindAllUsersBusiness) { }
  async handle(request: Request, response: Response) {
    const allUsers = await this.findUserBusiness.execute();

    return response.status(200).send({ allUsers });
  }
}
```

And finally my Business

```
class FindAllUsersBusiness {
  constructor(private usersRepository: IUsersRepository) {}

  async execute() {
    return this.usersRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined" because the `findUserBusiness` into handle function is undefined. And what I can't understand is that if I change my route to

```
routes.get("/users", (request, response) => {
  findAllUsersFactory().handle(request, response);
});
```

it works

I've tried to log the functions, but I can say why `findUserBusiness` is `undefined` since it came from the constructor, and since the handle functions came from an instance of `FindAllUsersController` it should have it "defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make some adjustments in order to adapt your factory to the way router.get expects its parameters.

```
const findAllUsersFactory = (req, res) => {
  const findAllUserRepository = new PrismaUsersRepository();
  const findAllUsersBusiness = new FindAllUsersBusiness(findAllUserRepository);
  const findAllUsersController = new FindAllUsersController(findAllUsersBusiness);

  return findAllUsersController.handle(req, res)
};
```

Then in your router you need to do the following:

```
routes.get("/users", findAllUsersFactory);
```

Comment: Hey Jone, tks for your answer. Weel this definitely works and looks better, but I can't understand why. In this way I'm just passing the function **factory** that should receive _req_ and _res_ as middleware, the same way my first attempt uses factory().handle that need same args

Comment: the problem with `this` in your class maybe is related to how you configured your tsconfig.json. Try settings interopModules = true